# Inconsistent summary of questions already answered on Superuser

Tags: bug, stackoverflow

I have noticed that Superuser inconsistently provides the summary of posts on the left has side of the question.

e.g. see the attached pic to understand my point:

1. First Q on the pic appears to have not been answered and no votes, also shows that this has been 'answered 4 hrs ago by ...'
2. Second Q on the pic show 1 answer with solid green in square background with a text "asked 5 hours ago by ..."

[image]

My issues are:

1. Why is the first Q not labelled that its been answered. Q1 was asked in 2011 and has got 4 answers altogether, with one of them being accepted perhaps in 2011 itself. So I expect this question to show a green square background with '4 answers' so that I do not click on this question and try to see if I can answer it
2. Why the statistics of how many hours before the questions has been asked / answered not consistent across the questions, sometimes it shows how many hours ago it was asked vs other times it shows how many hours ago it was answered.

I have seen both of these behaviors consistent on Stackoverflow site and am assuming that both stackoverflow and superuser are powered by the same underlying technology capabilities of the stackexchange sites.

Kindly help clarify!

Answer (score 9):

Search results and question lists appear similar, but have subtly different behavior and styles. You're looking at search results.

The first result is an answer.

The indicator is that it says "answered" in the bottom-right (as you observed), and also the "A:" prefix on the title.

To limit your search to questions, use the `is: question` operator.

See also: https://superuser.com/help/searching

Comment: many thanks for your explanation. Now I understand the differences between Q: and A:, I had missed seeing these on the first instance. However, part of the question still remains unanswered, why do the two platforms SE and SU behave differently and show the search results differently. Any help with the explanation will be great!!

Comment: Oh, other sites have a bunch of inconsistency as well. It really depends on what you search for.

Comment: Agreed @Shog9, but one inconsistency should not be the justification for another one!